# MySQL updating same row by multiple users like counter

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to increment a like counter for a users post. A post in my MySQL table has a field likes which shows how many likes this specific post has. now what will happen if multiple user like the same post at the same time? I think this will result in a conflict or not increment correctly? How can I avoid this, do I need to lock the row or which options do I have?

my query could look something like this:

```
UPDATE posts
    SET likes = likes + 1,
    WHERE id = some_value
```

also when a user unlikes a post this should decrement --> likes -1

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: `update` queries are atomic. if 5 people hit the same post at the same time, you'll do 5 updates, each of which can't affect the other ones. Not unless you round-trip the data through your client, which would be bad. e.g `update ... set views=views+1` is atomic. `select views; fetch views. views=views+1; update views` wouldn't be, and would allow trashing of counts.

Comment: Any way you can post your PHP? Maybe there is something going on there?

Comment: @MarcB Just because `UPDATES` are atomic does not mean you will get all five updates. *Atomicity* as it relates to an `UPDATE` means that updates are "an all nothing" proposition. "... --either the entire transaction is completed or none of it is." --Hess, *SQL Power*, 2007.  MySQL could have some sort of locking mechanism that, combined with buffers, could resolve race conditions, but I believe that is what transactions are for. Could be wrong, though.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge: it also means that if five separate `update foo set field=field+1` hit the DB at the same time, the end result is `field` being incremented by 5. it's not a sequence of "fetch value, update value, write value" where one query can stomp on another's updates

Comment: different beast. there's no transactions involved with any of the OP's code. It's just 5 updates. The `update` query itself is atomic. Without transactions involved, there is no way that update #2 could interefere with update #1 (or 3,4,5) because the update is atomic - it cannot be reduced to any smaller operations.

Comment: @MarcB Do you have a definition of atomic that you can share, because if all five queries are atomic yet can occur simultaneously, they will all end up updating the same beginning value by one and attempting to place result in the table. Scaled to 10,000 and you can see why this might be a problem.

Comment: atomic = cannot be divided into smaller operations. you really aren't getting this. the update cannot be subdivided at the "user" level. internally, yes, it will fetch the current value, it'll increment that value, it'll write that value back to the table. but since the update itself is atomic, those internal details are NOT interruptible by any other query. ONE of those "simultaneous" queries will win the race and do its update. so count goes (say) 5->6. then another of the other 4 will win and do 6->7, etc...  at NO TIME could it ever go 5->6->5->etc... that's what atomic means.

Comment: **IF** transactions were used, and one of those updates were rolled back, then yes, you could get a 5->6->5 sequence. but there are no transactions being used here.

Comment: @MarcB. Cite your reference. Division is not in question. Everything, in your view, is happening at the same time, which means all the `UPDATE` queries begin with the same beginning value. There must be order, or the value they end up putting in the table will be the same. It's called a race condition.

Comment: @MarcB What you are really referring to is the 'I' in ACID, isolation. "Some degree of isolation must exist for simultaneous transactions to be successful." --Hess, *SQL Power*, p. 37, 2007.

Comment: @MarcB An internal implementation of isolation in MySQL with the InnoDB and MyISAM storage engines. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-locking.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple enough query to run:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = mycolumn + 1;
```

That way even if you have multiple people liking at the same time the queries won't run at exactly the same time and so you'll get the correct number at the end.

Queries such as these run in fractions of a second, so you don't need to worry about multiple users clicking on them unless you've got millions of users, and then you'll have lots of problems to do with queries.

Comment: OK this is what I wanted to hear. Almost to easy. But I think it will do the job. If it will have a million users I'm sure I'll have a lot of other problems ;) thx!!

Comment: Transactions? Could they be an answer, too?

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Never used transactions so I don't know.

Comment: @user3216026 Often the simplest solution is the best. Thankfully many smarter people work to make it this easy for us :).

Comment: @Styphon Maybe, but not always.

Comment: If you're going to downvote please leave a comment why so I can improve my answer.

Comment: This would not work for a MyISAM table, given the question's scenario.

Comment: Can you please explain why it wouldn't?

Comment: @styphon, can you add where clause to your answer, to help newbies.

Comment: @Styphon, Could you listed the problems ?

Answer (score 3):

Someone liking the same post at the same time will only cause issues in long and complex queries.

This should be more than sufficient for an increment otherwise the entirety of SQL would be rendered useless.

```
UPDATE posts
SET likes = likes + 1
WHERE id = some_value
```

You could always run this query twice programmaticly and see what happens. I can guarantee that it will go from 0 to 2.

```
someTableAdapter.LikePost(postID);
someTableAdapter.LikePost(postID);
```

Comment: Good thing someone knows to add a condition/constraint to the update!!

Comment: If the OP actually used the "best answer" he/she will find the logic error pretty quickly. Well, I'd hope anyway.

Answer (score 2):

What you described is called a race condition (as in, race to the finish. Kind of like playing musical chairs with two people, but only one chair). I believe if you research transactions you may be able to implement your code and have pseudo-concurrent likes. Here's a link to the MySQL Manual.

[MySQL 5.1 Manual: Transactional and Locking Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html)

[YouTube: MySQL Transactions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9SLY3dly6E)

---

"MySQL uses *row-level* locking for **InnoDB** tables to support *simultaneous write access* by *multiple sessions*, making them suitable for *multi-user, highly concurrent, and OLTP applications*.

MySQL uses *table-level* locking for **MyISAM**, **MEMORY**, and **MERGE** tables, allowing only *one session* to update those tables at a time, making them more suitable for *read-only, read-mostly, or single-user applications*. "

[MySQL Manual, 8.7.1: Internal Locking Methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-locking.html)

---

But, if transactions are too much, make sure you are using at least the InnoDB storage engine and you should be alright if you are using an ACID compliant database with the the proper level of isolation.

There are lots of good references, but hopefully I've pointed you in the right direction.

Anthony

Comment: ok thanks for your respond. What do you think about @Styphon answer?

Comment: @user3216026 I think @Styphon's answer depends on `mycolumn` having a stable value, less I begin to miss count *likes*.  :-) However, it is clever. Just don't use it at a bank.

Comment: @user3216026  ...especially since @Styphon's answer would wipe out all like totals and make them equal to `mycolmn + 1`.  Don't forget to add a `WHERE` constraint to your SQL query.